# nginx - (http / https) non-www to www redirection

Tags: laravel, ssl, nginx, laravel-5, laravel-forge

I am have a website running on laravel 5 framework and hosted on DigitalOcean via laravel forge. I have just purchased a simple SSL Certificate from Namecheap for the sake of trying the certificate. Before installing the certificate everything was fine, i was able to load my website properly. After i install the certificate via Laravel Forge, my site is not loadable anymore (either http or https). I have no idea what is happening and from where to start debugging. Hopefully someone is able to provide me with some assistance.

I will provide you as much information as I can in below.

**Nginx.conf via Laravel forge**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /home/forge/www.example.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/10772/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/10772/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    client_max_body_size 128M;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**Server Details**
VPS Provider: DigitalOcean

Deployment: Laravel Forge

Platform: Ubuntu 14.04 x64 vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic

Framework: Laravel 5

Domain reg: Namecheap

DNS Svr: ns1,ns2,ns3.digitalocean.com

CA: Comodo PositiveSSL

**Update 1**: according to the buddy below suggested to check iptables, this is what i've got

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:https
```

**Update 2**: curl -i test does show that the site has now being redirected to a https:// connection. But browser says `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`

```
root@Apocalypse:/etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/10784# curl -i http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sat, 01 Aug 2015 09:52:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.example.com/

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.8.0</center>
</body>
</html>
root@Apocalypse:/etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/10784# curl -i http://www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sat, 01 Aug 2015 09:53:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.example.com/

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.8.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update 3**: openssl s_client return with this error

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
140000289871520:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 295 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

**Update 4**: I have found out the issue.. apparently this line

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

is causing the issue. once i remove it then everything works like a charm... but now my problem is how should i reroute `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`? Suppose that the above code is to perform that action.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information on 'not loading anymore'?

Comment: @Wizzard if you use google chrome it says ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: @Wizzard I hosted it in DigitalOcean using Laravel Forge, most of it has been automated. What i do now is i dump the whole droplet and try recreate it from fresh again. I'll keep you updated as well as your answer...

Comment: Did you check first?

Comment: @Wizzard yes i did, you can see in my latest update. also i tried your suggestion to restart nginx, i even restarted and province my server. No luck :(

Comment: Send a support ticket to the forge guys, seems something a bit off with the SSL. Did you add (it ask) for the peer certificate?

Comment: @Wizzard i've added from the root down to my domain certificate in order...

Comment: Have you stored it out?

Comment: @Wizzard pls see update 4 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I have resolved the issue. Now where do I start.

**First**

I would like to clarify that there is no problem with the certificate, Laravel forge and nginx configuration file. Everything was well setup and well configured.

**Second**

Like what I have done in my question above, configure your nginx.conf like such:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/10772/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/10772/server.key;

    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /home/forge/www.example.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/10772/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/10772/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    client_max_body_size 128M;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Note that there is one thing I would like you to pay attention on in this section. When you are redirecting a https connection (port 433 to port 433), you are required to specify again the certificates and keys to be use. Naturally when the server performs a redirect, a new connection is being established therefore a new handshake sequence is required. That is why in my `https://example.com` redirection

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/10772/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/10772/server.key;

    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

I would have to re specify the certificates or else the server will drop the connection since there is no credentials to be validated with. Once you have done with this, you should be half way till completion.

**Third**

In order to have a proper redirection, there are a few things you need to check and make sure it is configured properly.

1. Domain names to be configured in your DNS provider and your Hosting
   provider must consist of both www and non-www A(Host) registry and
   point to the same ip.
2. Make sure that your name servers are able to resolve non-www addresses (with or without https) into your desired address. Which in my case all `http://example.com`, `http://www.example.com`, `https://example.com`, into `https://www.example.com`. Performing this check you can use like @Wizzard's suggestion `curl -i http://example.com/`

**Finally**

Once everything has been properly configured, you should be on your way to a secured connection browsing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you access the port 80 or port 443? Try running a 
`curl -i http://example.com/` on your command line, whats the error?

Can you check the nginx logs?
Is nginx even running, maybe restart it again?

`service nginx restart`

What about the firewall, is that open for port 443?

Checked iptables if installed?

`iptables -L`